# Regex expression in Validation Rule

Tags: validation-rule, regular-expressions

I have the following validation rule with regex expression. I have tested the expression working to my need but can't able save this coming up with syntax error could someone help me to get this cleaned.

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Processing'),
$RecordType.Name = "Carer Card", 
NOT(ISBLANK( Carers_Other_Phone__c)), NOT(REGEX( Carers_Other_Phone__c, "^(\(((0|\+61(\ |-){0,1}0{0,1})(2|4|3|7|8)){0,1}\)|((0|\+61(\ |-){0,1}0{0,1})(2|4|3|7|8)){0,1}|((\+61(\ |-){0,1}\(0{0,1})(2|4|3|7|8)){0,1}\))(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}$")))
```

Answer (score 0):

It just needs \\ is all escapes.

```
AND( 
ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Processing'), 
$RecordType.Name = "Carer Card", 
NOT(ISBLANK( Carers_Other_Phone__c)), NOT(REGEX( Carers_Other_Phone__c, "^(\\(((0|\\+61(\\ |-){0,1}0{0,1})(2|4|3|7|8)){0,1}\\)|((0|\\+61(\\ |-){0,1}0{0,1})(2|4|3|7|8)){0,1}|((\\+61(\\ |-){0,1}\\(0{0,1})(2|4|3|7|8)){0,1}\\))(\\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}(\\ |-){0,1}[0-9]{1}$")))
```